# Create pandas dataframe column with random conditional numbers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random, conditional-statements

I have created the following pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds = {'col1' : [1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
      'col2' : [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
```

which looks like this:

```
print(data)

    col1  col2
0      1     0
1      1     0
2      1     0
3      1     0
4      1     0
5      1     0
6      1     0
7      1     0
8      1     0
9      1     0
10     1     0
11     1     0
12     1     0
13     1     0
14     2     1
15     2     1
16     2     1
17     2     1
18     2     1
19     2     1
20     2     1
21     2     1
22     2     1
23     2     1
24     2     1
25     2     1
26     2     1
27     2     1
```

I need to create a new column (called `col3`) subject to the following conditions:

1. when `col1 = 1`, there are 14 records for which col2 = 0. The new column (i.e. `col3`), needs to have 50% (of exactly those 14 records) of the values equal to `col2` (randomly distributed across the 14 records) and the remaining 50% equal to 1.
2. when `col1 = 2`, there are 14 records for which `col2 = 1`. The new column (i.e. `col3`), needs to have 50% (of exactly those 14 records) of the values equal to `col2` (randomly distributed across the 14 records) and the remaining 50% equal to 0.

So, the resulting dataset would look like this (bear in mind that the location - or record - of the values in `col3` is randomly assigned):

[image]

Does anyone know the python code to produce such dataframe?

Comment: Are you sure you described your conditions correctly? Your description of condition 1 and condition 2 seem identical to me.

Comment: Let me edit it with more clarifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `groupby` + `sample`

```
# take a sample of 50% from col2 per unique value in col1
data['col3'] = data.groupby('col1')['col2'].sample(frac=.5)

# fill the remaining 50% using a predefined mapping of col1 value
data['col3'] = data['col3'].fillna(data['col1'].map({1: 1, 2: 0}), downcast='infer')
```

Result

```
    col1  col2  col3
0      1     0     1
1      1     0     0
2      1     0     0
3      1     0     0
4      1     0     0
5      1     0     0
6      1     0     0
7      1     0     1
8      1     0     0
9      1     0     1
10     1     0     1
11     1     0     1
12     1     0     1
13     1     0     1
14     2     1     1
15     2     1     0
16     2     1     1
17     2     1     0
18     2     1     0
19     2     1     1
20     2     1     1
21     2     1     0
22     2     1     1
23     2     1     0
24     2     1     0
25     2     1     1
26     2     1     1
27     2     1     0
```

Comment: Assuming 0/1, another way with your approach: `data['col2'].eq(data.groupby('col1')['col2'].sample(frac=.5)).astype(int)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `df.sample()` method to isolate all the subgroups randomly within the condition, and then assign the values

```
ds = {'col1' : [1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2],
      'col2' : [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1]}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=ds)
data['col_3'] = 0
```

sets up the dataframe and creates a new, empty column

Now let's select by condition

```
cond_1 = data.loc[(data.col1==1)&(data.col2==0)]
cond_2 = data.loc[(data.col1==2)&(data.col2==1)]
```

Get a random 50 % of the first condition, and then get the remaining 50%

```
cond_1_A = cond_1.sample(frac=.5)
cond_1_B = cond_1.loc[cond_1.index.difference(cond_1_A.index)]
```

For each sub-group, set the value to 0 or 1

```
data.col_3.loc[cond_1_A.index] = 0
data.col_3.loc[cond_1_B.index] = 1
```

Second Condition -  Same Thing

```
cond_2_A = cond_2.sample(frac=.5)
cond_2_B = cond_2.loc[cond_2.index.difference(cond_2_A.index)]
data.col_3.loc[cond_2_A.index] = 0
data.col_3.loc[cond_2_B.index] = 1
```

That should do it.

Run 1

```
data
    col1    col2    col_3
0   1   0   0
1   1   0   1
2   1   0   1
3   1   0   0
4   1   0   1
5   1   0   1
6   1   0   0
7   1   0   0
8   1   0   0
9   1   0   1
10  1   0   0
11  1   0   0
12  1   0   1
13  1   0   1
14  2   1   1
15  2   1   1
16  2   1   0
17  2   1   0
18  2   1   0
19  2   1   0
20  2   1   1
21  2   1   0
22  2   1   0
23  2   1   1
24  2   1   1
25  2   1   1
26  2   1   0
27  2   1   1
```

Run 2

```
data
    col1    col2    col_3
0   1   0   1
1   1   0   0
2   1   0   1
3   1   0   1
4   1   0   1
5   1   0   0
6   1   0   1
7   1   0   0
8   1   0   0
9   1   0   0
10  1   0   1
11  1   0   0
12  1   0   0
13  1   0   1
14  2   1   1
15  2   1   0
16  2   1   0
17  2   1   1
18  2   1   1
19  2   1   1
20  2   1   1
21  2   1   0
22  2   1   1
23  2   1   0
24  2   1   0
25  2   1   1
26  2   1   0
27  2   1   0
```